# Avoid Checked event to be fired when setting ischecked to true

Tags: silverlight, events

in my silverlight application, I have a checkbox :

```
<CheckBox Content="Check me" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
```

IsChecked property is binded to a property in my viewmodel :

```
    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isChecked == value)
                return;

            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
```

In my viewmodel, I have :

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    IsChecked = true;

    DataContext = this;
}

private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // IsChecked = true fired the event
}
```

The problem is that the checked event is fired althought I'm setting the IsChecked Value manually. This values comes from configuration and is setted as initial value and shouldn't fire event that does business ...

How can I avoid this event to be fired ?

(this is a easy-to-reproduce sample, in fact, the event is bound to a command)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: 'In my viewmodel, I have :' You mean in your View's code behind I guess?

Comment: Here, this is a code behind and a viewmodel. In my real code, only a viewmodel

Comment: Doesn't setting up the initial value on the member variable instead of property fix your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wire up the event handler after initialization:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="theCheckBox" Content="Check me" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    IsChecked = true;

    DataContext = this;

    theCheckBox.Checked += CheckBox_Changed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would default the private variable to true, as well as in the binding, set FallbackValue=True, so it has that as the default value.  If it's just a case, where you do not want the event fired if it's EVER set to true, do not fire the OnPropertyChanged event if "value=true".  But what I think you want is the first option, just the defaulting of that variable to true without firing off the event.  The FallbackValue plus targeting the private member and not the public property should cut it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and solved it by doing what Phil suggests, but instead of doing it on `MainPage()` I do it when the checkbox is loaded. This works for me.